# TextView Overflow not handled correctly

Tags: android, overflow, textview, android-tablelayout

I am using a TableLayout that contains TableRows.
The TableLayout :

```
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/window"
            android:minWidth="256dp"
            android:id="@+id/charStanceList"></TableLayout>
```

Those rows are inflated from this xml file :

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="None"
        android:id="@+id/stanceHands"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/list_text" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="None"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/stances"
        android:textColor="@color/list_text" />

</TableRow>
```

And here is the code that is used to create the rows :

```
    public TableRow createTableRow(Context context) {
        TableRow row =(TableRow) ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE )).inflate(R.layout.stance_list_row,null);
        TextView hands=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.stanceHands);

        hands.setText(RHand + LHand);

        TextView stancesView =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.stances);

        MovementMethod movementMethod = stancesView.getMovementMethod();
        if ((movementMethod == null) || !(movementMethod instanceof LinkMovementMethod))
        {
            stancesView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
        SpannableString finalss=new SpannableString("");
        for (Stance s : stances) {
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s.getName());

            class StanceLink extends ClickableSpan{
                Stance stance;
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.i("Clicked", "clicked on stance "+stance.getName()+" of ClassID "+stance.ClassID);
                }
                public void setStance(Stance st){
                    stance=st;
                }
            }
            StanceLink link=new StanceLink();
            link.setStance(s);
            ss.setSpan(link, 0, s.getName().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE  );
            finalss= new SpannableString(TextUtils.concat(TextUtils.concat(finalss,ss),"\n"));
        }
        stancesView.setText(finalss);
        return row;
    }
```

A break line is inserted when the string is too wide, but a part of it will be hidden (on the right). In this image the text used is : The Five Books of Martial Arts - The Book of ...
The "Arts - " seems to overflow so we can't see it.
Here is a screenshot of the problem

[image: screenshot]

Changing the Ellipsize doesn't work.

Comment: check for parent layout it must not have `layout_width` set to have `wrap_content`.

Comment: My TableLayout indeed is in a LinearLayout that has layout_width set to wrap content, but the whole thing is in another LinearLayout, which has match_parent, is it the problem ? I have another textview before the TableLayout, and it works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it thanks to android:shrinkColumns and changing widths to match_parent

the tablelayout :

```
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/window"
            android:minWidth="256dp"
            android:id="@+id/charStanceList"
            android:shrinkColumns="1"></TableLayout>
```

The rows

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="None"
        android:id="@+id/stanceHands"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/list_text" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="None"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/stances"
        android:textColor="@color/list_text" />

</TableRow>
```